# Recursion – Printing a Sequence of Numbers

Tags: c#

this is the sequence

***1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16, 22, 29**....*

need to print series as above using recursive function

Comment: A question from the test .. no doubt. :)

Comment: What the stop condition. You always need a stop condition otherwise you'll have stack overflow (the real one).

Comment: First, work out the pattern (It's not that complicated). Then, I'm sure you can work it from there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public void Numbers(int iteration, int number, int limit)
{
  if(iteration < limit) {
    Console.WriteLine(number);
    Numbers(iteration + 1, number + iteration);
  }
}

Numbers(0,1,5);
```

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't even write it as recursion:

```
static IEnumerable<int> Generate() {
    int value = 1, inc = 0;
    while(true) {
        yield return value;
        value += inc++;
    }
}
```

Recursion is generally bad if too deep... Then:

```
foreach(int x in Generate().Take(n))
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

You could also just loop and print in a single method... But where would be the fun in that?

(this approach chosen deliberately to show a useful technique while not directy being usable as a homework answer)

Comment: +1: Excellent use of `IEnumerable` and `yield return`.  Students can learn more from code like this than they can from most test questions :)

Comment: @David - especially if they think about things like "how does this actually get around to printing anything? Doesn't it loop forever first?"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void PrintNumbers(int current, int index)
{
 Console.Write(current + ", ");

 PrintNumbers(current + index, index + 1);
}

PrintNumbers(1, 0);
```

Note that this recusion does not terminate, so running it will result in a StackOverflowException.